# How can I edit the objects within custom AS3 components using MXML?

Tags: actionscript-3, layout, flex4, mxml, flash-builder

I'm writing a Flex application using Flash Builder 4 and I'm having a bit of trouble with an AS3 object. Essentially, it is a BorderContainer, with a few buttons and images, and programming logic that determines how these interact with eachother and a database.

What I want to be able to do is configure the layout/style of the inner components using MXML and CSS. I can configure the inherited objects, but not ones that I have defined...

For example, in my MXML. I can modify the (inherited) *borderstroke* variable of myContainer like so;

```
<IE:MyContainer>
    <IE:borderStroke>
        <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="10" rotation="270">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xF655E5"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color="0x6600CC"/>
        </s:LinearGradientStroke>
    </IE:borderStroke>
</IE:MyContainer>
```

However, I can't edit the *nextButton* variable (which is of type Button) like this;

```
<IE:MyContainer>
    <IE:nextButton width="100" height="30" left="10%" bottom="10%"/>
</IE:MyContainer>
```

If I try, I get the compile error "Could not resolve  to a component implementation".

What do I need to do to make this work?!

Thanks in advance,
Aidan

EDIT:
Here's the main method of MyContainer (actually named InvestigativeEnvironment).
The call to defineTestInvestigativeEnvironment() is what takes care of setting up the objects and action listeners and such. What I want to do is change the layout and appearance of these visual components in MXML (nextButton, prevButton, toolbox, displayArea). I want to be able to set their height, width, background, x, y, horizontalCenter, etc like I can to a button that I add to a container via MXML.

```
public class InvestigativeEnvironment extends BorderContainer
    {
        private var toolbox:Toolbox;        
        private var bodySystem:BodySystem;      
        public var nextButton:Button;
        public var prevButton:Button;       

        private var displayArea:Group;
        private var image:Image;    
        private var toolDisplayArea:Group;

        public function InvestigativeEnvironment()
        {
            super();

            //create 'Next' button and event listener
            nextButton = new Button();
            nextButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextViewAngle);
            nextButton.label = "Next";
            this.addElement(nextButton);

            //create 'Prev' button and event listener
            prevButton = new Button();
            prevButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevViewAngle);
            prevButton.label = "Prev";
            this.addElement(prevButton);

            //define investigative environment by creating models.
            defineTestInvestigativeEnvironment();   

            //Instantiate the Group that contains the model image and tool overlays
            displayArea=new Group();

            //Instantiate the image that is used to display the model
            image = new Image();    
            image.source=bodySystem.getImage();
            image.horizontalCenter=0;
            image.verticalCenter=0;
            displayArea.addElement(image);

            //add toolOverlayContainer to the display area ABOVE the model image            
            toolDisplayArea = new Group();
            toolDisplayArea.verticalCenter=0;
            toolDisplayArea.horizontalCenter=0;
            displayArea.addElement(toolDisplayArea);

            this.addElement(displayArea);

            //add toolbox to display
            toolbox = new Toolbox(toolDisplayArea);
            toolbox.replaceTools(bodySystem.getToolGroup());
            this.addElement(toolbox);
        }
```

Comment: Please add code listing what is your edits are and what line in particular produces this error.

Comment: post your code for <IE:MyContainer>

Comment: @Constantiner Just a second... adding the code in the comments isn't going so well. I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I wasn't quite asking the right question. I wanted to edit the components, but specifically the layout and color type attributes of them.

What I need to do is set the id of the components, and then target them using CSS.

For my *nextButton*, I add the ID like this;

```
nextButton.id="nextButton";
```

Then I can lay it out in the MXML file (or external stylesheet) like this;

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace IE "InvestigativeEnvironment.*";

    IE|InvestigativeEnvironment s|Button {
        chromeColor: #336666;           
    }

    #nextButton {
        bottom: 100;
        right: 5;
    }       
</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what is your problem with editing button in particular, sorry for that. But I have a lot of notices about your `InvestigativeEnvironment` which code you've attached.

First, you haven't follow Flex components livecycle (see [here](http://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/flex-component-life-cycle/) or [here](http://danorlando.com/?p=122)). So in your code you should add and configure children in `createChildren()` method.

But anyway you can't use your container to add children both with MXML and from code. If your adding custom components code will be executed first MXML (in your implementation with adding them in constructor it is so) all the MXML tags just remove all your added content (anyway result will be unpredictable). In other case it will be very hard to control instance's order.

I can suggest you to declare your `nextButton` etc as skin parts and perform their positioning in skin. This way these internal controls will be a part of border and you can add MXML children without any problem. And you can configure them within `partAdded()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I am very new to Flex, and am still quite unsure about how MXML works...

I don't actually want to add new components using MXML. I just want to configure the components that are already there. My initial example was quite unclear, sorry. I've worked out that I can do what I want by setting `nextButton.styleName="testStyle";` and using a stylesheet that addresses `.testStyle` to set the position and colours.